# On Ajax error send form without Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
$("#contactform").validate({
    rules: {
       // ...
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(form).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
                    url : formURL+'validate',
                    type: "POST",
                    data : postData,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {

                            $.ajax({
                                url : formURL,
                                type: "POST",
                                data : postData,
                                beforeSend: function (){
                                   // ...
                                },

                                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                                {
                                   // ...
                                },
                                error: function(jqXHR, exception)
                                {
                                    $(form).submit();
                                },
                                complete: function (){
                                  // ...
                                }
                            });
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, exception)
                    {
                        $(form).submit();
                    }

                });
    }
});
```

In 2 places I have `$(form).submit();` - I would like in this places to send form not using AJAX (url after submitting should change to the one in action attribute of form).

At the moment it seems data is being sent using AJAX - when I add alert to send `$(form).submit();` alert is being displayed one after another (I've prepared PHP script to return incorrect data)

*** EDIT ***

My code after change is:

My form beginning

```
<form method="post" action="{{ current_url }}" id="contactform" onsubmit="return formAjaxSubmit(this);">
```

My full AJAX code:

```
   $("#contactform").validate({
        rules: {
            content_{{ hash_tag }}: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 20
            },
            name_{{ hash_tag }}: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            subject_{{ hash_tag }}: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            },
            email_{{ hash_tag }}: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {

        }
    });


    function formAjaxSubmit(form) {

            var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(form).attr("action");
            $.ajax({

                        url : formURL+'validate',
                        type: "POST",
                        data : postData,
                        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                        {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url : formURL,
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data : postData,
                                    beforeSend: function (){
                                        if(data.valid == 1) {
                                            $(form).hide();
                                            $("#formsending").show();
                                        }
                                    },

                                    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                                    {
                                        $('#articlecontent').html(data.content);
                                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
                                        return false;
                                    },
                                    error: function(jqXHR, exception)
                                    {
                                        return true;
                                    },
                                    complete: function (){
                                        if(data.valid == 1) {
                                            $("#formsending").hide();
                                            $(form).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, exception)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }

                    });

    }

</script>
```

But now I have a problem with validating fields using jQuery. When I click submit even if form is not completed, form is being sent (via AJAX) what makes that even if jQuery validation is made, just after it there are results from PHP validation shown. If I remove `onsubmit` from form and in submitHandler I have:

```
formAjaxSubmit(form);
```

everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Where is your form code? I suspect its getting into a loop: you submit (submitHandler sends via ajax), onError - form resubmits (submitHandler sends via Ajax, error occurs again, onError - form resubmits (submitHandler sends via Ajax) and so on

Comment: My form is standard HTML form, nothing special. I know it's sending in this case via AJAX so I'm asking if it's possible to resend form in error not using AJAX. For standard AJAX errors (loading page content) without form I can simple use `window.location.href = url;` which reloads page not using AJAX

Comment: See my solution in the answers below. It atempts to do ajax submission, if ajax fails you return true, forcing the form to submit via traditional method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposed solution is

```
<form action="nonAjaxSubmitHandler.php" onsubmit="return tryAjaxSubmit();">
...
</form>


function tryAjaxSubmit() { 
  // Ajax code - on success
  return false; // stops form submitting via http post

  // On error
  return true;  // form will submit via http post
}
```

As pointed out in the comments (thanks ElmoVanKielmo), you might need to set the `async: false` option, in your jquery post (after the success: and fail: options).

The onSubmit forces the form to run the tryAjaxSubmit(), and depending on the outcome of this method, the form will either submit or not submit via HTTP POST (or GET).

So in the tryAjaxSubmit, we attempt our Ajax code:

- if it is successfull, we return **false** (so the form is not manually submitted
  and the page is not refreshed)
- if there was an error we return **true** and the form is submitted manually

---

Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ current_url }}" id="contactform" onsubmit="return formAjaxSubmit(this);">

<script>
function formAjaxSubmit(form) {
  // Do validation
  $("#contactform").validate({
    rules: {
      //....
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      // When form is validated, submit via ajax
      var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
      var formURL = $(form).attr("action");
      $.ajax({
        url : formURL+'validate',
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
          ...
          return false
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception)
        {
          return true;
        }
      });
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery AJAX callbacks can't interfere with the event handler. The handler continues to execute and eventually exits even if the AJAX request is still running.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo - it can. The form will not submit until the tryAjaxSubmit returns. And it will not return anything if you set your ajax callback to be synchronous using jQueries "async:false" option

Comment: @Husman It seems that's something I need but I will have to divide my validate method somehow to validate without submission and sending when onsubmit is launched. I'll try it later today

Comment: @Husman I've added edit to my question. At the moment I don't know how can I make those 2 things to make work - jQuery validation and handling error as described at the beginning

Comment: @Husman I tried it but in this case validation is not being done "live" but only after submit clicking

Answer (score -1):

My assumption is that since submit handler is attached already, so while you are doing another submit, it is calling submit handler again.

Do not try to submit same form and try generating another form with action url and serialized data from current form to another form.

Please find below solutions for submitting data
 1. Remove submit handler and then call submit(). Page will refresh and submit handler will be attached again.
 2. Use one variable to store the error flag (which i will not recommend, however still a way). And use this flag in submit handler before sending AJAX request.